# modifying results in python numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a response from a kerras prediction that looks like this (y_pred):

```
array([[127450.63 ],
       [181983.39 ],
       [150607.72 ],
       ...,
       [460400.   ],
       [ 92920.234],
       [244455.97 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I need to compare the results to another array that looks like this (t_pred):

```
[105000. 172000. 189900. ... 131000. 132000. 188000.]
```

How would I go about converting array 1 to look like array 2 so I can calculate its mean_square_log_error, like this?:

```
mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`reshape(-1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) or [`flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred.ravel())
```

Or

```
mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred.reshape(-1))
```

Or

```
mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred.flatten())
```

**Example:**

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
>>> y_pred = np.array([[127450.63, 181983.39,181983.39 ]]) 
>>> t_pred = [105000., 172000., 189900.]
>>> mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred.ravel())
0.01418072635060214
>>> mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred.reshape(-1))
0.01418072635060214
>>> mean_squared_log_error(t_pred, y_pred.flatten())
0.01418072635060214
```